# Common content of two Dockerfiles

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a docker configuration that I want to run both locally and on the CI (Github).

The only difference in the Dockerfiles is the `FROM` directive:

- local configuration uses Nexus (behind firewall)
- CI configuration uses Github Container Registry (GHCR)

Rest of the configuration is exactly the same (base images are the same images, just pulled from different source).
Now the majority of Dockerfile content and files that are copied into image need to be duplicated in both env specific directories.

I'd like to have common Dockerfile configuration in case of any changes needed.

#### Current state example:

- `local/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM nexus.example.com/myapp/app:latest

{several lines of code}
```

- `ci/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ghcr.io/mycompanyapp:latest

{the same several lines of code as above}
```

#### Desired:

- `common/Dockerfile`:

```
{common code}
```

- `local/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM nexus.example.com/myapp/app:latest

# INCLUDE ../common/Dockerfile
```

- `ci/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ghcr.io/mycompanyapp:latest

# INCLUDE ../common/Dockerfile
```

I am aware of existence of the `edrevo/dockerfile-plus` but I am looking for more official solution. It was tedious to link Dockerfile residing in different directory than build context.
Also it seems that it is not maintained actively and it may not work on Windows which is used by other team members (issue https://github.com/edrevo/dockerfile-plus/issues/27)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ARGS do to this.

```
ARG REPO=nexus.example.com
FROM ${REPO}/app:latest
....
```

So the default config will be nexus.example.com and in your CI you just need to build with arg REPO=something

example:

```
docker build -t myapp:latest --build-args REPO=ghcr.io -f Dockerfile
```

For local build:

```
docker build -t myapp:latest -f Dockerfile
```

Comment: Oh it is really that simple! Thanks